# Popup screen opens behind the screen in ie 11 latest version

Tags: internet-explorer, jqgrid

I am opening a pop up when double clicking a row in jqgrid(version 5.2.0) by using window.open function.
Pop up is opening behind the parent in IE 11(version 11.0.9600.19463).It is working correct in other browsers and other versions of IE. Problem occur when opening by double clicking the grid only, in the same page popup is opening by clicking a button, it is working correct. Can someone help me with this issue.?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What is your OS version? Version 11.0.9600 seems not the latest version of IE 11. I made a test in [my IE 11 version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYiN7.png) **11.116.18362.0** on **Windows 10** and the pop up works well. I use the function like this:

```
ondblClickRow: function (rowId) {
    window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank", "width=800, height=800");
}
```

You could check [my example](https://jsfiddle.net/yuzhou0602/3erft4b5/2/) in IE 11. The result is like this:

[image]
You could update IE 11 to the latest version and refer to the code I provide. If the issue still occurs, it could be better that you provide [a simple sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried your code. it is working fine for me . But when I give an aspx page instead of google.com in your code , it is not working.    window.open("https://www.allegianceretailservices.com/MemberPortal_testsite/Default2.aspx", "_blank", "width=800, height=800");    window.open("Default2.aspx", "_blank", "width=800, height=800"); tried both these code, but not working. Default2.aspx is a  blank aspx page .. I am using windows 7 professional. I have checked machines with windows 10. It is working fine in windows 10.

Comment: Yes, it works fine in Windows 10 IE 11. It might be a bug of using jqgrid in Windows 7 IE 11. You could try to contact jqgrid official to fix the bug or move to the latest version of Windows 10 and IE 11.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to contact them